# How to put a string to make a query using PHP CodeIgniter

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, string, codeigniter

I have different strings that is made by multiple checkboxes when is checked and I would like to use this strings to make a query.

For example:

If I click a specific sequence of checkboxes this returns me this value of string:

```
"SELECT Call_Setup FROM lte_kpi.vw_main_kpis_cidade_rate_daily WHERE node != 'UNKNOWN' and node = 'ABADIA DE GOIÁS' and date between '10/02/2017' and '10/18/2017' order by date"
```

I save this query into a variable called query1. What I would like is to put this variable (query1) like parameter to perform a query.

This is my model:

```
<?php 
class Model_KPI_Customize extends CI_Model{

function kpi_customize_CustomQuery(){               
$query = $this->db->query(/*I would like to put my string here !*/); 

return $query->result();

}
}
?>
```

This is my Controller

```
public function highcharts_teste(){
$this->load->model('model_kpi_customize');
$data['kpi_customize_string_CustomQuery'] = $this->model_kpi_customize
->kpi_customize_CustomQuery();
}
```

And I have a view with multiple checkboxes and one paragraph element which I would like to display the result of a query.

In the example above I would like to return the following values like this, because this is the result when I query it on Database:

```
99.73
99.48
99.51
99.40
99.23
99.34
99.29
99.10
99.23
99.11
```

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Just a tip your naming your classes and filenames wrong http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Call_Setup 
FROM 
       lte_kpi.vw_main_kpis_cidade_rate_daily 
WHERE 
       node != 'UNKNOWN' and 
       node = 'ABADIA DE GOIÁS' and 
       date between '10/02/2017' and '10/18/2017' 
order by date
```

Can be written using active_record like below

```
$where = array(
                   'node' => 'ABADIA DE GOIÁS',
                   'date >=' => '10/02/2017', 
                   'date <=' => '10/18/2017' 
              );

$this->db->select('Call_Setup')
         ->get_where('vw_main_kpis_cidate_rate_daily', $where )
         ->order_by("date", "asc");
```